# DatePickerDialog save layout on screen rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, screen-orientation, android-datepicker

I have strange problem.
I have `Activity` inherite from `AppCompatActivity` with Fragment inside.
In this `Fragment` I show `DatePickerDialog` to select date.

A declared `Activity` in `manifest.xml` as

```
<activity name=".SampleActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" />
```

now.
I want to show `DatePickerDialog` inside `Fragment` so I created custom `DatePickertFragment` with code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment{
    // (...)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        return dialog;
    }
    // (...)
}
```

and execute show() method inside fragment

```
 pickerFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), null);
```

I run show picker code inside `onClick()` method. `DatePicker` shows correctly.

And now is problem. 
`Dialog` show correctly in portrait screen orientation but when I rotate screen to landscape mode dialog seems to be cut on left and right size. 
I checked and I suppose that `Dialog` picker didn't change layout orientation on screen rotate.
Screenshots below
1. Portrait orientation, correct dialog
[image]

2. Next I rotate device and in landscape mode I getting something like cut dialog (landscape dialog layout in dialog portrait layout dimensions)
   [image]

I changed `manifest.xml` `Activity` declaration to

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

And now is work correctly but I can't do this, because other app part will work incorrect. 
So I wonder if I can invalidate or redraw `DialogPicker` to resize it boundaries after I rotate screen?

Comment: The issue here is that the date and time picker widgets are both purposely designed so that if they are started in a layout and that activity declares that it handles BOTH orientation and screen size then it will decide that it cannot change it's orientation correctly. I've brought this up as an issue before but google seems to think it's not a problem
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199701&thanks=199701&ts=1453899881

Comment: The simple solution is that, if you can, don't add the screenSize declaration to the manifest.

Comment: Is seams that remove screenSize from activity declaration is the best solution for now. Thanks for the link to issue report. I think that might be a serious problem for many developers. I spend almost one day to find and fix this issue in my app.

Comment: I found second consequence of using "screenSize". Not only Date/Time pickers are infected by this bug but optional menu also has bug. When I fist open menu in portrait mode I can see all menu items or I can scroll menu items list. But when I rotate device the menu won't be smaller and when I have a lot of item in menu I can't see all because in landscape mode menu is size like in portrait mode and scroll finish in middle of menu.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` to handle calendar crop issue checkout my code is working 100% with screenSize. startDateDpd is Date picker dialog,startDateTxt - on click of this date picker dialog opens

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(startDateDpd!=null)
    if(startDateDpd.isVisible()){
        startDateDpd.dismiss();
        startDateTxt.performClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Sumedh Ulhe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52422586/4472843)'s answer, I find out that DatePicker/TimePicker will load layout on creating time.

You can see the `android-26\android\widget\TimePicker.java`

```
mDelegate = new TimePickerClockDelegate(
```

and `android-26\android\widget\TimePickerClockDelegate.java`

```
final int layoutResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.TimePicker_internalLayout,
    R.layout.time_picker_material);
```

There are two R.layout.time_picker_material: `android-26\data\res\layout\time_picker_material.xml` and `android-26\data\res\layout-land\time_picker_material.xml`

So I re-create the picker when picker is already opened

```
mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
...
@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (pickerDialog != null && pickerDialog.isShowing()) {
        pickerDialog.dismiss();
        pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), (picker, year, month, 
            day) -> {
            // Do something
        }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        pickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your @LucasHuang you can upvote if  you find my answer helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenLayout"
```

or manage on the method:

```
onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem, but with TimePicker. I putting it in FrameLayout and it's was fixed.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to make it one that directly answers the original question posted?